# How to set capacity when initialize a map can prevent rehash

Tags: dictionary, go

```
s := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0}
capacity := len(s)
m := make(map[int]bool, capacity)
for _, n := range s {
    m[n] = true
}
```

Does the map will rehash in the for loop? 
Or the capacity should multiply by a factor to prevent rehash, like:

```
capacity := len(s) * 1.3
```

Comment: The language spec makes no promises here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a factor. [Spec: Making slices, maps and elements:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels)

> Calling `make` with a map type and size hint `n` will create a map with initial space to hold `n` map elements. The precise behavior is implementation-dependent.

Also from the doc of the builtin [`make()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#make):

> Map: An empty map is allocated with enough space to hold the
>   specified number of elements. The size may be omitted, in which case
>   a small starting size is allocated.

Answer (score 0):

This code is the most optimal and does not need to be changed as long as values of the `s` are less than `capacity`

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

const (
    bucketCntBits = 3
    bucketCnt     = 1 << bucketCntBits
)

type emptyInterface struct {
    _type unsafe.Pointer
    value unsafe.Pointer
}

// A header for a Go map.
type hmap struct {
    // Note: the format of the hmap is also encoded in cmd/compile/internal/reflectdata/reflect.go.
    // Make sure this stays in sync with the compiler's definition.
    count     int // # live cells == size of map.  Must be first (used by len() builtin)
    flags     uint8
    B         uint8  // log_2 of # of buckets (can hold up to loadFactor * 2^B items)
    noverflow uint16 // approximate number of overflow buckets; see incrnoverflow for details
    hash0     uint32 // hash seed

    buckets    unsafe.Pointer // array of 2^B Buckets. may be nil if count==0.
    oldbuckets unsafe.Pointer // previous bucket array of half the size, non-nil only when growing
    nevacuate  uintptr        // progress counter for evacuation (buckets less than this have been evacuated)

    extra *mapextra // optional fields
}

// mapextra holds fields that are not present on all maps.
type mapextra struct {
    // If both key and elem do not contain pointers and are inline, then we mark bucket
    // type as containing no pointers. This avoids scanning such maps.
    // However, bmap.overflow is a pointer. In order to keep overflow buckets
    // alive, we store pointers to all overflow buckets in hmap.extra.overflow and hmap.extra.oldoverflow.
    // overflow and oldoverflow are only used if key and elem do not contain pointers.
    // overflow contains overflow buckets for hmap.buckets.
    // oldoverflow contains overflow buckets for hmap.oldbuckets.
    // The indirection allows to store a pointer to the slice in hiter.
    overflow    *[]*bmap
    oldoverflow *[]*bmap

    // nextOverflow holds a pointer to a free overflow bucket.
    nextOverflow *bmap
}

// A bucket for a Go map.
type bmap struct {
    // tophash generally contains the top byte of the hash value
    // for each key in this bucket. If tophash[0] < minTopHash,
    // tophash[0] is a bucket evacuation state instead.
    tophash [bucketCnt]uint8
    // Followed by bucketCnt keys and then bucketCnt elems.
    // NOTE: packing all the keys together and then all the elems together makes the
    // code a bit more complicated than alternating key/elem/key/elem/... but it allows
    // us to eliminate padding which would be needed for, e.g., map[int64]int8.
    // Followed by an overflow pointer.
}

type maptype struct {
    typ    _type
    key    *_type
    elem   *_type
    bucket *_type // internal type representing a hash bucket
    // function for hashing keys (ptr to key, seed) -> hash
    hasher     func(unsafe.Pointer, uintptr) uintptr
    keysize    uint8  // size of key slot
    elemsize   uint8  // size of elem slot
    bucketsize uint16 // size of bucket
    flags      uint32
}

type tflag uint8
type nameOff int32
type typeOff int32

// Needs to be in sync with ../cmd/link/internal/ld/decodesym.go:/^func.commonsize,
// ../cmd/compile/internal/reflectdata/reflect.go:/^func.dcommontype and
// ../reflect/type.go:/^type.rtype.
// ../internal/reflectlite/type.go:/^type.rtype.
type _type struct {
    size       uintptr
    ptrdata    uintptr // size of memory prefix holding all pointers
    hash       uint32
    tflag      tflag
    align      uint8
    fieldAlign uint8
    kind       uint8
    // function for comparing objects of this type
    // (ptr to object A, ptr to object B) -> ==?
    equal func(unsafe.Pointer, unsafe.Pointer) bool
    // gcdata stores the GC type data for the garbage collector.
    // If the KindGCProg bit is set in kind, gcdata is a GC program.
    // Otherwise it is a ptrmask bitmap. See mbitmap.go for details.
    gcdata    *byte
    str       nameOff
    ptrToThis typeOff
}

func mapTypeAndValue(m interface{}) (*maptype, *hmap) {
    ei := (*emptyInterface)(unsafe.Pointer(&m))
    return (*maptype)(ei._type), (*hmap)(ei.value)
}

func main() {
    PredefinedSizeMap()
}

func PredefinedSizeMap() {
    m := make(map[int]int, 1000000)
    _, hm := mapTypeAndValue(m)

    fmt.Printf("Elements | h.B | Buckets\n\n")

    fmt.Printf("%8d | %3d | %8d\n", hm.count, hm.B, 1<<hm.B)

    for i := 0; i < 1000000; i++ {
        m[i] = i * 3
    }

    fmt.Printf("%8d | %3d | %8d\n", hm.count, hm.B, 1<<hm.B)
}
```

output:

```
    Elements | h.B | Buckets

       0 |  18 |   262144
 1000000 |  18 |   262144
```

we can see buckets num not change, no rehash